# Whether a holomorphic f(z) exists on D(0,1) \ {0} such that $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 0}$ |z|f(z) = 1

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I am not sure if this way of solving is correct, but here's my attempt.

For the limit to exist, we suppose f(z), a holomorphic function exists where f(z) = $\frac{1}{|z|}$ on D(0,1) \ {0}

However, f(z) = $\frac{1}{(z\bar{z})}$ where there exists zbar and hence f(z) is not holomorphic.

Thus, there does not exist any f(z).

Comment: But $1/|z|$ is not the only function with $\lim_{z\to0}|z|f(z)=1$. There are many others, and you have to prove that _every single one_ is non-holomorphic, or that there exists _one_ which is holomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in the comments, you have only shown that a certain
function $f$ does not satisfy the conditions, but you have to show
that *no* holomorphic function $f$ with that property exists.

So assume that $f$ is such a function, and define $g$ in 
$\Bbb D \setminus \{ 0 \}$ by $g(z) = zf(z)$.
Then $g$ is *bounded* in a neighborhood of $z=0$, and
[Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem)
states that $g$ has a removable singularity at $z= 0$.
In particular, $\lim_{z\to 0} g(z)$ exists (and is not zero).

It would follow that
$$
 \frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert} = \frac{g(z)}{\lvert z \rvert f(z)}
$$
has a limit for $z \to 0$, which is not the case: The left-hand side
is equal to $1$ for positive real $z$, and equal to $-1$ for negative 
real 
$z$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I have another question after reading your comments. Actually my goal was to determine if |z|$^\frac{1}{2}$* f(z) has a limit of 1 as z tends to 0. Using your idea, I was able to let g(z) = z$^\frac{1}{2}$ * f(z). 

However, when comes to the limit  part, I've got $(\frac{z}{\bar z})^\frac{1}{4}$ but I am unsure whether this limit exist.

Because the limit I've evaluated to is 1 and (-1)^0.25 (which is not real)

Any idea how to prove this limit does not exist or this is the correct way? :) Thanks!

Comment: @Bread: In that case $g(z) = zf(z)$ has a removable singularity with $g(0)=0$, so $g(z) = z^k + ...$ for some $k$. This also leads to a contradiction. Alternatively, consider the Laurent-expansion of $f$ in an annulus.

Comment: Hi Martin, I apologise, but after looking at your first solution again, im puzzled as to how you are able to get a zbar at the denominator. Do you meant using g(z) = z^2 * f(z) for |z|f(z)?

Another question would be, can i suppose that |z| = |z|$^\frac{1}{2}$ = 1 in this case, since its a unit disk.

Comment: @Bread: That was indeed an error, which is fixed now.